# Changing attributedText value of ASTextNode makes parent node flash

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I'm changing an existing project to `AsyncDisplayKit/Texture`. I just got to the last part of my new `ASTableNode`, where I've encountered a bug. In my `ASTableNode`, there's a `ASTextNode`. Now after I receive a notification I try to change the `AttributedText` of said `ASTextNode`, but when I do this, it makes the parent node flash. (See GIF here:)

[image]

Is there an explanation for this? The `AttributedText` is changed like this:

```
self.likes.countLabel.attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(newCount)", attributes: self.likes.font)
```

Is this perhaps a threading issue, or has anyone else faced a bug like this before?

Thanks.

Comment: need a simple example project with it issue. 
This can be associated with a hierarchy of conversion calls. Try to play with `[self.likes.countLabel setNeedsLayout];` method after setup new attributedString.

Comment: its because changing text node width causes the entire cell gets relayout. set a break point in your cell layout spec block and see it gets relayout or not.

Comment: @HashemAboonajmi Yep, you're right. Any way to prevent this?

Comment: @WesleyPeeters Separate the cells and start working with sections instead of cells.

Comment: modify your layout spec, create a sub node named `ActionBarNode` and define those buttons there with there specific layout, then add this sub node in the cell, see the result.